# BRATA (Brazilian RAT Android) - is there any action and treatment from it?

Tags: security, reboot, system-apps, motorola, antivirus

As far as is known, with ***this virus***, the attacker, in addition to stopping antivirus programs, can also block the system menu while working with it by the user. The virus copies system data and then stops whatever it wants?